# Is there a good approximation for this Gaussian-like integration?

Tags: integration, gaussian

Is there an analytic solution or approximation for the following Gaussian-like integration? $\frac{1}{\eta^{2n}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\eta}^{+\eta} e^{-x^2/2} x^{2n} dx$?  The numerical plot suggests that it initially decrease faster, but reach a steady decrease of $(2n)^{-1.06}$ numerically when $2n > 100$ for all $\eta$.

[image]

Comment: The integral is asympotically $Θ(1/n)$, so the $1.06$ is actually $1$. Are you asking for the coefficient in the $Θ$?

Comment: Write $x^{2n} = e^{2n \ln  x} $. When $n$ becomes large, the integrand is strongly peaked around the maximum of the exponent, i.e., at $x=\sqrt{2n} $. If that's within the range of integration, saddle point approximation should be good.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt  I understand the question as $n→+\infty$ for fixed $η$, so $x=\sqrt{2n}$ is outside the range of integration.

Comment: @LeechLattice Ok, then the dominant contribution comes from the endpoints, $x=\pm \eta $.

Answer (score 1):

An exact result (in terms of the incomplete Gamma function) and the large-$n$ asymptotics are as follows:
$$\frac{1}{\eta^{2n}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\eta}^{+\eta} e^{-x^2/2} x^{2n} dx=\pi^{-1/2}2^{n}  \eta^{-2 n} \left[\Gamma \left(n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)-\Gamma \left(n+\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}\eta^2\right)\right]$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{e^{-\eta^2/2} \eta}{\sqrt{2 \pi } n},\;\;\text{for}\;\;n\gg 1.$$
The convergence to the large-$n$ result is shown in the plot for $\eta=5$ (blue is the integral, gold the large-$n$ value):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you send me your address so that I can acknowledge you properly? It still looks like that the trend is less than 1/n

Comment: Can you give me a link to the 2nd gamma function which has two arguments? I can only find the definition for the first one at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function ; no need for an acknowledgment, but for completeness, the proper way to refer to MO postings is explained here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4352/11260

Answer (score 0):

See paragraph 3.8 in https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~%20jburkardt/presentations/truncated_normal.pdf and https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/YoniNazarathy/teaching_projects/studentWork/EricOrjebin_TruncatedNormalMoments.pdf where  recursive Formulas are given for the moments of a truncated normal distribution.

Comment: For the truncated normal distribution, is there a formal publication? I am using truncated normal distribution in my paper, so that I'd like to reference it.

Comment: For example https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Normal-Distribution-Second-Statistics/dp/0824793420

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica 12.0 answers

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[Exp[-x^2/2]*x^(2*n), {x, -\[Eta], \[Eta]}, {n, Infinity, 1},
Assumptions -> n>0&&n\[Element] Integers && \[Eta] > 0]/  Sqrt[2*Pi]/\[Eta]^(2*n)//Simplify
```

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{\eta ^2}{2}} \eta ^{-2 n} \left(\eta ^2\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } n} $$

Comment: Thanks you so much! Can you send me your address so that I can acknowledge you properly?

Comment: The answer seems can be simplified further as $ \frac{e^{-\frac{\eta^2}{2}} \eta}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Yes, the command of Mathematica Simplify[%, 
 Assumptions -> n > 0 && n \ [Element] Integers && \ [Eta] > 0] performs $$\frac{e^{-\frac{\eta ^2}{2}} \eta }{\sqrt{2 \pi } n} .$$